# Reboot error after changing desktop environment

Tags: 14.04, unity, dual-boot

I changed my desktop environment to LXDE then I removed LXDE and installed XFCE along with my Unity desktop.
The automatic login was disabled in my unity desktop.
Now when I start ubuntu it directly login me and it shows Grey screen with nothing not even mouse pointer. I have tried many solution on askubuntu. Some of them are as follow.
When i press ALT+CTR+F4 it takes me to command prompt 
I tried to config lightdm.config using

pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit etc/lightdm/lightdm.config

but its giving error

“error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.”

I have also tried it with sudo.

Please help me resolve this problem
I have also tried ubuntu recovery mode.

I am using dual boot with windows 8.1

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling lightdm from the same session as when you press alt+ctrl+f4?

Comment: let me try reinstalling

Comment: @Horizon can u tell me command

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

The idea is that the reinstallation should rewrite all the config files and hopefully appropriate variables with right values.

**Update:**

Since, reinstalling didn't help, reconfigure the post login setup.  As root, try:

```
sudo mdmsetup
```

Under **Options**, check the selected value.  First try

**Run Xclient script**

and reboot.  If that doesn't work then change it to

**XFCE Session**

.

Comment: I tried this but not working yet

Comment: any other help ?